# と in the first sentence + た in the second sentence

Tags: particle-と

I already learned how と functions. It is used when we’re talking about natural things. When something happens another thing always happens too.
I sometimes see と sentence like this one:

> 街灯じゃ暗い**と**　カラスが頭上で笑った

Does this 笑った only present the past (I don’t understand why past verb is used with this と)? Or does it have any other different meaning?

Answer (score 4):

Have you learned about quotative-と, which is typically used with 思う, 考える, etc? This と is not "when/if", but quotative. That is, 街灯じゃ暗い is what the crow "said" or "thought" (of course it's a personification).

> 街灯じゃ暗いと　カラスが頭上で笑った
>   A crow laughed, (as if saying) "Street lights are dark!"

笑った is just the past tense of 笑う, and it has nothing to do with this usage of quotative-と.

Comment: Thank you very much !